# Chrome Extension notification only shows-up once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

This verifies whether the page is https and whether a localStorage item evaluates to true or false, and displays a notification based on that. The code is placed in the popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
 active: true,               
 lastFocusedWindow: true    
    }, function(array_of_Tabs) {

    var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];
    var url = tab.url;

 if (url.indexOf('https:') === 0 && localStorage.getItem("secureRead").value !== true) {
           chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().showNotify();
       }
    });
```

The actual notification code is placed in the background.js file:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  'icon48.png',
  'Secure page detected.',
  'Checking "Enable HTTPS reading" in the setting is required.'
);

function showNotify()
{
  notification.show();
}
```

The problem is that this only works once, globally. No other page is then detected, evaluated and no notification is shown. What am I doing wrong?

There are no errors thrown at me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be aware that the current notification system (i.e. webkitNotifications.createNotification) is deprecated, and has been removed from Chrome, at least on Windows and ChromeOS. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html for details.

Second, the notification might be null if it's closed by the user; I'd try this:

```
function showNotify()
{
    if (notification == null)
    {
        notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                         'icon48.png',
                         'Secure page detected.',
                         'Checking "Enable HTTPS reading" in the setting is required.'
                       );
    }
    notification.show();
}
```

Comment: That was it. I just needed to add this, add an similar "else" and also define notification outside the function as a global variable because it threw out an undefined, it's not working perfectly. Thank you.